# ErrorException in Mailer.php line:242 Undefined offset using php laravel

Tags: php

i have a problem while sending the mail ErrorException in Mailer.php line:242 Undefined offset 1. This is my Controller

```
    class ContactController extends Controller
{

     function store(Request $request){



        $data= array( 
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'subject'=>$request->subject,
            'comment'=>$request->comment,
            );


Mail::send(['emails.contact'], $data, function ($m) use ($data) {
            $m->from($data['email']);
            $m->to('neeraj.karki17@gmail.com');
            $m->subject($data['subject']);


    });
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what line 242 is. So what is line 242?

Answer (score 1):

Use 'emails.contact' instead of ['emails.contact'].
Or

```
$template = 'emails.contact';

Mail::send($template, $data, function ($m) use ($data) {
            $m->from($data['email']);
            $m->to('neeraj.karki17@gmail.com');
            $m->subject($data['subject']);


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check syntax in invoice.blade.php file

it might be a div or html error

i was facing the same issue and found this was the problem